# Accessing the javascript's global variable the second time results in undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = 10;
   window.onload = function() {
      document.write(this.x); // <-- yields correct output: 10.
      document.write(this.x); // <-- outputs "undefined"
      document.write(this.x); // <-- outputs "undefined"
   }
</script>
```

I am unable to understand why [this.x] results in undefined from the second time onwards. If I am correct, the function context (value of "this"), would refer to the global window object.

Comment: *outputs "undefined"* -- Actually, it doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/dt4dg/ You are doing something different from what you show here.

Comment: I would just output it to a DOM element using innerHTML, or log it to the console

Comment: @Tomalak: I am absolute positive, what i have written is what i am doing :).  My intention to write this code was to understand "this". Point me in right direction, if in case i am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @thescientist: Is there any problem if i use document.write(this.x)?

Comment: @jfriend00: It's nothing special i want to achieve here. It's just the five lines of code I want to execute. That's it. The reason to post this query is, if I write document.write(x), it works fine. But if i write document.write(this.x), it fails to execute. Just want to understand, why is this happening?

Comment: We don't see problems in our attempt to simulate your error.  If you want further help, you will need to state exactly what your browser environment is and perhaps put a sample web page on the internet that shows the problem (because we don't see the problem when we try it).  The main issue is that you're doing two things you should not do (so you're asking for trouble in some browsers).  You should not be using `this` to access global variables and you should not be using `document.write()` after the document has loaded.  More details in my answer below.

Comment: Guys, is there any connection between "document.write(...)" and "this"? Because using "alert" instead of "document.write(...)" yields perfect result.

Comment: @jfriend00: BROWSER: Firefox 10.0.2, IE 9. I am new to stackoverflow. Can you please point me, where should I put up my sample code? I agree i shouldn't be using document.write: I am using just for sample purpose and not in any project. Regarding using "this", i don't find any good reason not to use "this". You can think of a situation where you can call a function directly (where this would refer to global object) and indirectly (using call/apply, passing an object, where this would refer to the object passed in the call/apply).

Comment: Please read my answer below.  I have explained in that answer why you should NOT be using `document.write()` in this circumstance and why it may cause problems in some browsers.  Please read that answer.  I've written a lot in that answer.  If you want to unambiguously access global variables, use `window.x`.  Please continue this conversation after you have read my answer below and you can comment further there.

Comment: As has been stated repeatedly, the issue is using document.write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `document.write()` AFTER the document has loaded, it opens a new document (clearing the previous one).   It appears that in some browsers (IE, for example), the global variables are immediately wiped out, even from the script that is still running that did the `document.write()`.  The best answer here is to not use `document.write()` after the page has loaded.  Instead, use DOM manipulation to change the existing document however you want it changed rather than creating a new document.  You can see that things work fine (based on your more recent code example) if you use DOM manipulation (manipulating innerHTML) rather than using `document.write()` in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s22aT/).

Since clearing the current document is almost never what you want to do, if you can explain what you're really trying to accomplish we can help better with a solution.

If you want to `modify` the existing document after it has loaded, you need to use DOM manipulation functions such as `.innerHTML` (to change the HTML of a node) or DOM manipulation functions to add new nodes to the existing document, NOT `document.write()`.

You should generally not use `this` to refer to global variables.  Global variables are available with no prefix (unless overriden locally) or available with the `window` prefix.

So, either of these will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = 10;
   window.onload = function() {
      console.log(x);
      console.log(x);
      console.log(x);
   }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = 10;
   window.onload = function() {
      console.log(window.x);
      console.log(window.x);
      console.log(window.x);
   }
</script>
```

As to your question about using `this`.  The value of `this` is set one of several ways:

1. When you call a method on an object such as `pleasures.makeIceCream()`, the value of `this` will be set to the `pleasures` object in the `makeIceCream()` method.
2. When you use the `call` method on function objects like `makeIceCream.call(pleasures)`, then the value of `this` will be set to the `pleasures` object in this invocation of the `makeIceCream()` method.
3. When you use the `apply` method on function objects like `makeIceCream.apply(pleasures)`, then the value of `this` will be set to the `pleasures` object in this invocation of the `makeIceCream()` method.

You can read more about `.call()` and `.apply()` in these MDN references:

apply: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

At all other times, the value of `this` should generally not be used as it has not been explicitly set.  It is likely set to the global object (in a browser, this is the `window` object) , but it is not considered best practice to use it to access global variables, nor is there any reason to.

Comment: I agree with you on the concept, and I would used the best practices in my project. But as you told: "At all other times, the "this" would refer to global object", I just want to understand, whats the problem accessing document.write(this.x) the second time onwards. For this sample, I am focusing on the concept and not the best practices. I hope you understand my concern. If i write "alert" instead of "document.write", it works fine.

Comment: @AnupVasudeva - Probably the first `document.write()` wipes out the existing document (in some browsers) and all its global variables as a brand new document is created.  Thus anything that used to exist as a global object would no longer exist.  As I've said four times, now don't use `document.write()` after the document has loaded.  What part of this am I not communicating effectively?

Comment: Your jsFiddle works fine in Chrome, doesn't work in IE.  Obviously IE behaves differently when you use `document.write()` after the document has been loaded.  It loses access to global variables in running scripts, where Chrome doesn't.  What you are doing is not a supported behavior.  There are other ways to do that (direct DOM manipulation) that don't have this issue.  That would be the way to solve your issue.  To prove this, try [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s22aT/) in IE.  It works fine when not using `document.write()`.

Comment: I agreed with you before, that document.write isn't a good practice at all. I also conveyed my intention, as it's just for the sample purpose, and not for best practice (though i appreciate your effort). All I want to understand why Javascript behaves in this way if I write such code. This will help other people understand that there maybe some connection between document.write and global variables. Rest, I am also researching more on this.

Comment: It is clear that IE removes access to the global variables from a running script when you use `document.write()` after the page has loaded.  My point was that it's a bad practice and there are better ways to accomplish modifying the document so I'm unsure why you're spending time trying understand the browser-dependent behavior of a bad practice that has an alternative that is a good practice.  I think I've said all I can say here.

Comment: I agree with your comment. It's supported atleast in Opera/Chrome, but not in IE. Better alternative too. Oh!, honestly speaking, I didnt know this was a browser dependent concern, until I ran it in opera and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

since it is a global variable, you need not use object. try this

```
var x = 10;
window.onload = function() {
    document.write(x);
    document.write(x);
    document.write(x);
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dt4dg/1/

Comment: Thanks rajkumar. I know this works well. But I am trying to figure out the reason why document.write(this.x) doesn't works. When the window.onload function gets called,  the function context (this) will always be a window object.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use this:

```
document.write(x);
```

Since it is defined outside of the function it can be called within the function.

Comment: Is there any issue prefixing "this" with x?

Answer (score 0):

It ain't working because you is calling document.write after page has loaded. Calling write will implicitly mean you are creating a new page immediately. The new page does not understand the value of x.

Comment: but it seems the Javascript is understanding "document.write(x)" and not "document.write(this.x)". Is there any difference between the two?